# Multiple grounds errata corrige?

Tags: ground, isolation, split, split-supply

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbmruE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is a thought (hopefully) to my grounding/shorting problem ([Multiple ground](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594167/multiple-ground)).

Would this circuit work being fed by the li-ion cells to obtain an isolated +-3.7V?
What kind of transformer should I look for? Like key parameters.
(please don`t mind the values)

NOTE: I realized that i drow the two ground connections the same, please refer to those as two separate GND connections

Comment: What is the question? Reading the datasheet for the LT3436 doesn't look like you should be connecting the NC pins to ground...

Comment: You should also really use named nets instead of running lines all over the place. For example, U5 has "VIN" pin 8 connected directly to GND if you trace it back up to CN2 pin 3. And for some reason you have TS from U2 skipping over a bunch of ground connections to connect to GND from CN2 as well...

Comment: Ok, about the NC pins I don't think makes difference if they are connected to gnd. If you look at the suggested layout they are indeed grounded. About the TS running all the way I guess you are right, but it is for me to remember that the NTC is to be place underneath, or as close to, the battery pack.  Then I am having hard time trying to get the "virtual ground" right in order to split my battery voltage in two

Comment: With respect to "different" Ground nodes, if you are looking for a general procedure I suggest this: 1) Make all grounds a single net GND. 2) analyze if this leads to any problems. 3) determine specific solutions to these problems. Specifically, are you sure you need galvanic isolation ?

Comment: This appears to be an addendum to a previous question, and should be an edit to that question. Posting extra information as a new question just makes things confusing for people trying to help.

Comment: @Hearth: got it

Comment: @tobalt: thanks I will try to proceed step by step from single gnd net

Comment: @Hearth - Agreed, *but* making substantial updates to the schematics in the [original question](/questions/594167) could render the existing answers there to be obsolete - or at least confusing, as older answers would address the original schematic & newer answers would address new schematics. This is one reason why broad design review-type questions are not well-suited to the Stack Exchange Q&A format, as the questions can change after initial answers are given. So I can see both sides - we don't want to invalidate previous answers, but yes, this is only a "next stage" on a journey. Thoughts?

Comment: [continued] If there were no answers on the original question, then this would definitely be better as an edit to that question. However that isn't the situation in this case :-(

Comment: the `do not populate` directive does not indicate which components are affected

Comment: What is the point of isolating from a battery?  If it is battery powered, why not make ground the mid point between the batteries and then run the LDOs directly from the battery?

Comment: Because they need to get charged. And they get charged from usb

Comment: Disconnect the batteries from the LDOs when you charge them.  Or do you need to be to run off of USB power (without batteries) too?

Comment: I gave for granted that it would have worked also during charge. I never thought about power also from usb (which sounds interesting:). But in case that when it charges does only that, how would you disconnect them?

Comment: Take the batteries out and put them in a charger or add a transistor that disconnects on USB insertion. This is common, lots of hardware cannot be used while charging.

Comment: Yeah taking batteries out is a no go. I don't like it. Not considering it. Add a transistor that disconnects on USB insertion: could you be a little bit more specific?